# TYPO3 realURL Autoconf to manual conf

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a TYPO3 site that's been running with realURLs autoconf for years.

The pattern is very simple: Domain/language/pid
e.g. example.com/d/6

Now I have to make an addition to the realURL config, but I'm not sure on how to reproduce the setup by autoconf in a manual configuration file (we don't want to change the URLs)

How's that done? I've tried outputting the serialized autoconf values via var_export(), but no work.

Or: how can I create the URL pattern above in realurl_conf?

Thanks!
Urs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's quite easy:

1. In `Extension Manager` (`EM`) find the RealURL and set option `Automatic configuration file format` to `PHP source (slow!)` (with automatic conf still **enabled**!)
2. Remove the file `typo3conf/realurl_autoconf.php` (as far as I remember), clear all caches and refresh the main page, the autoconf file will be recreated in unserialized version.
3. Rename the file to `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`, go to EM again and uncheck the `automatic configuration` option.

After clearing the caches and you'll be switched to manual config built from the automatic one.